# Trackable entities Primary key violation EF 4 Issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

My situation is very wierd. We have a .NET 4.5 Application that uses Tracking Entities using EF 4. Everything works fine in our DEV/QA/UAT environment. But EF fail in Production with a Primary key violation. We have a Table  and a  that has a foreign key with the Parent Table and that foreign key is also the primary key in the Child table.

The code that does the update gets the  entity that also has the  entity referenced in it. We start tracking on the  and the  in the Business Layer and then do a few updates and then pass to the Data Access layer to do the actual update. The code in the Data access layer is below:

```
    internal static TEntity EntitySave<TEntity>(this TEntity entity, bool      
    enableTracking = true) where TEntity : class, IObjectWithChangeTracker
    {
        if (entity == null)
            return entity;

        MasterEntities context = null;

        try
        {
            context = new MasterEntities();
            if (!entity.ChangeTracker.ChangeTrackingEnabled)    // This code isn't really doing anything since turning on tracking at this point doesn't matter
            {                                                   // ""
                entity.StartTracking();                         // ""
            }                                                   // ""
            context.EntityRoot<TEntity>().ApplyChanges(entity);
            context.SaveChanges();
            if (enableTracking)
                context.ResetAllTracking();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            new GroupM.ToolLib.AppException.Ex(false, ex, "Error in RepositoryHelpers; Method: EntitySave",
                            GroupM.ToolLib.AppException.ExType.Error,
                            GroupM.ToolLib.AppException.ExDestination.AppDefaultLogFile);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (context != null)
                context.Dispose();
        }

        return entity;
    }
```

The stack trace is:

> Exception=An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner
>   exception for details.  Method=Update  Source=System.Data.Entity 
>   StackTrace=   at
>   System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager
>   stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)    at
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
>   at
>   DataMarketplace.DataAccess.Repositories.RepositoryHelpers.EntitySave[TEntity](TEntity
>   entity, Boolean enableTracking) 
>   InnerException=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904):
>   Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_DataFeedQueries'. Cannot
>   insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.DataFeedQueryState'. The duplicate
>   key value is (3383). The statement has been terminated.    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader
>   ds)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task,
>   Boolean asyncWrite)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)    at
>   System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(UpdateTranslator
>   translator, EntityConnection connection, Dictionary`2
>   identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues)    at
>   System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager
>   stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)
>   ClientConnectionId:9abb68fe-3424-45d8-a174-88ed692ac5fd  Custom
>   Message Text=Error in RepositoryHelpers; Method: EntitySave  Machine
>   Name=WEB02-PROD

I have done the following to troubleshoot:

1. Debug the issue from my local machine and point to production database, it works fine. So it led me to believe maybe the code is not the same.

   2. I copied code from our UAT environment where this is working to Production web server. But I still get the same error. This led me to believe maybe the database schema or some other setting is not the same.
   3. Compared database schema between UAT and Prod. They are identical.

Any ideas on how to further troubleshoot this. Been trying for a couple of days now.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you're managing the primary keys manually instead of the database.

If that is the case, you might get two concurrent inserts for the same table with the same id, violating the Primary Key constraint.

Comment: No the primary key is in the database and the EF model is based off the database schema.

Comment: Yes. The primary keys are in the database. But how is the value of those primary keys generated? By code or automaticly by the database?

Comment: Automatically by the database. It's an identity column

Comment: can you show me the output of the following query in production database? `DBCC CHECKIDENT ('DataFeedQueryState', NORESEED);`